# Django Countries - unable to pre-select the right country in an edit form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-countries

Consider this model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    postcode = UppercaseCharField(max_length=64, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm trying to populate this model using data that comes in through webhook call. I'm having trouble populating the country in two cases:

When the country is "United States" (this is what the webhook returns, I have no control over it) - django_countries does not recognize this, so I added an if condition to change "United States" to USA before creating a new Address object but, when the country is not United States, for example "Panama", I populate it directly into the model by doing this:

```
country = request.POST.get('country')    # returns something like "Panama"
Address.objects.create(line1=line1, city=city, state=state, country=country)
```

This works fine, except when I try to edit the Address form, the country field is blank, it isn't pre-selecting "Panama" from the options. I know the `country` field of this Address instance is a country object because I can do `address_form.instance.country` and it outputs `Pa`, if I do `address_form.instance.country.name` it outputs `Panama`. So why isn't the country field in the form pre-selecting the right Country, why does it show blank?

This is my model form:

```
class NewAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['line1', 'city', 'state', 'postcode', 'country']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewAddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my template [showing just the country field here]

```
 <div class="col-md-5">|

     {% comment %}
     COUNTRYCode: {{address_form.instance.country.code}} ---> Outputs Pa in case of Panama
     COUNTRYName: {{address_form.instance.country.name}} ---> Outputs Panama in case of Panama
     {% endcomment %}

     <div class="form-group">
         <label>{{address_form.country.label}}</label>
         {% render_field address_form.country class="form-control m-b" name="country" id="country_dropdown"%}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What about problem about United States: I think the best option for you to customise country names as described [here](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/#customization).

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE = {
    'NZ': _('Middle Earth'),
    'AU': None,
    'US': {'names': [
        _('United States of America'),
        _('America'),
    ],
}
```

2. Have you tried to use `CountrySelectWidget` like [this](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/#countryselectwidget)? If no, could you try and say is it working for you correctly?

```
from django_countries.widgets import CountrySelectWidget

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ('name', 'country')
        widgets = {'country': CountrySelectWidget()}
```

Comment: I did try CountrySelectWidget and it does nothing more than just add the selected country flag as a label beside the text box. I don't see it doing much more than that. Perhaps I am wrong? Is there any other benefit to using CountrySelectWidget?